# Unpacking values from a file read and assigning to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following short program:

```
data = []
f = open('C:/tsg3.txt', 'r').read().split("\t")

for i in range(0, len(f)-1):
   [GeneID, Sym, Alias, Xref, Chromo, Cyto, Full_name, Gene_type, Desc, Nuc_seq, Pro_seq = f[i]
```

I am seeing the appearance of a ValueError (need more than 4 values to unpack).
Obviously, I am doing something wrong since I am relatively new to Python.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm using Python 3.3.2.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show sample `tsg3.txt` content?

Comment: What is your expected output here? And the code you've has a syntax error.

Comment: http://bioinfo.mc.vanderbilt.edu/TSGene/Human_716_TSGs.txt Please ignore the first line (column headers). Thanks.

Comment: Vague guess: You split the _file_ by tabs. Instead, I think, you should first split it by lines (e.g., `splitlines()`, and then by tabs (i.e., `f[i].split(\t)`).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: The syntax error is the ValueError right? I am attempting to assign the tab separated values to the appropriately named variables.

Comment: You have a one-dimensional list, so `f[i]` is *one* element, a string of 4 characters.

Comment: Note that not all the lines in the file have 11 elements. Particularly, the _first_ line (with the headers) has only 10 elements. One of the tabs separating the headers is a space, and there are probably more errors like this in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You split the whole file by tabs, resulting in a single list of strings.

You then loop over that list, assigning `f[i]` (individual strings) to a long list of variables. From your error message, you are trying to assign a 4-character string to those variables, leading to individual characters being assigned, which fails because the number of characters doesn't match the number of variables.

Most likely, you want to process a tab-delimited file. Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for such tasks:

```
import csv

with open('C:/tsg3.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        # `row` is a list of columns.
```

Because the file has headers, you can also use a `csv.DictReader` and use dictionaries instead (keyed with the headers):

```
with open('C:/tsg3.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        # `row` is a dictionary of columns.
```

Not all rows have all values; some appear to be missing Nucleotide_Sequence and Protein_Sequence columns.

For future reference, you can loop directly over a python list, there is no need to use indices with a `range()`:

```
for i in f:
    # do something with the individual elements of `f`, assigned to `i` each iteration.
```

Comment: Oh, how embarrassing. Thanks for the help MartijnPieters, matino, tobias_k, and ashwinichaudary.

Comment: That was my guess too, but additionally it seems like the lines do not all have the same number of tab-separated elements...

Comment: @tobias_k: No, `f[i]` is a **string**, which is a sequence too. A string of 4 characters in this case.

Comment: @tobias_k: ah, no I see what you mean, the file has lines between 9 and 11 elements.